# typescript w/ angular loading bloburl into img not working

Tags: angular, typescript, canvas, angular5

I'm having problems converting a svg blob to a png via canvas.

Here my code:

```
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const data = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svg);
const svgBlob = new Blob([data], {type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'});
console.log(svgBlob, canvas);
const img = new Image();
const url = URL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);

img.onload = (() => function () {
      console.log('inside onload');
      ctx.canvas.width = size;
      ctx.canvas.height = size;
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      const imgURI = canvas
        .toDataURL('image/png')
        .replace('image/png', 'image/octet-stream');

      DownloadModalComponent.triggerDownload(imgURI);
});
img.src = url;
console.log(img.complete,  img.currentSrc);
```

This worked previously with plain javascript (well some jquery).

The console is outputting for img.complete false and currentSrc is empty.

In the network tab I can see that the local svg url is fetched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let svgSource = "yourSVGcodehere"; // string of your <svg></svg>
let data = "data:image/svg+xml," + encodeURIComponent(svgSource);
let ctx = my2dcanvas.getContext("2d"); // my2dcanvas is your canvas element
let img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        my2dcanvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
        doSomethingWithBlob(blob) // funciton processing the blob
        // clear canvas context:
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 320, 320)
    }, 'image/png');
};
img.src = data;
```

This is a prod working snippet. Let me know if helps

Comment: Hey, Thx for your reply! it helped my a lot. the problem seems that img.onload doesn't like `() => function() {` I worked around it now, but is that a bug or my mistake?

Comment: so you are trying to do anonymous function in your snippet and I am not sure why would you want that:) another one thing - I used to have the code like yours where I would create svgBlob etc and I had issues with some browsers. Then i saw someone did it this way (using data string) and since that worked I figured its more elegant solutoin